# Can't populate TableView with Realm object

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I'm using Realm and can't populate my tableview with Realm object. It works if I assign a plain String to the textLabel, but not with the realm object.

It works for the object Deck which contains a Realm List of Flashcards

[image]

But if you go to a course, it won't show the flashcards. As mentioned before, if I assign a plan string in cellForRowAt it works.

[image]

If I print the Realm from the cellForRowAt function it shows the right value

[image]

the function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FlashcardCell", for: indexPath)

    let flashcard = flashcards[indexPath.row]

    print(flashcard)

    cell.textLabel?.text = "hi"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = flashcard.name

    return cell
}
```

my model

```
class Deck: Object {

    let flashcards = List<NewFlashcard>()

    @objc dynamic var name: String?
    @objc dynamic var color: String?
}
```

Comment: Please don't post *code images*, post text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was that I forgot `dynamic`

```
class NewFlashcard: Object {

    @objc dynamic var name: String?

}
```